# Is "remains" in "Xenophobia remains in our society" a linking or intransitive verb?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Yet another grammar question.

I know that 'remains' can be a linking verb in many contexts, but I'm undecided on whether it is  linking in the sentence "Xenophobia remains in our society".

I feel that "in our society" doesn't restate or rename xenophobia, and I feel it answers the question "Where does xenophobia remain?", making "in our society" an adverb of place. But certainly you can describe some societies as xenophobic.

So what characterization is appropriate in this case?

Comment: English may be hard, but you're making it harder than it has to be by over-thinking it. And where did you get the notion that a linking verb can't be intransitive? That contention [seems](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/seem) rather difficult to prove.

Comment: I think you're agonising between categorisations that are actually fairly pointless...!

Comment: @Robusto: ...but an instance of a verb can normally not be both at the same time.

Comment: @NeilCofey: I think the distinction is in many cases quite useful, though I agree that it is less useful in borderline cases like this one.

Comment: @Cerberus: My point is simply that I can't think of a single exclusively transitive verb that can function as a linking verb. Can you?

Comment: @Robusto: Nope: but linking verbs are by definition intransitive, so that shouldn't come as a surprise.

Comment: @Cerberus: My point exactly. Maybe you should reread my comment, this time for wry humor.

Comment: @Robusto: Oh, in that way. I took the OP's "intransitive verb" to mean "a simple intransitive verb, as opposed to a linking verb", but, granted, he didn't express himself clearly.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "too localised". In this case, *"remains"* could be parsed as synonymous with *"survives", "persists"*, etc., which don't actually *require* any supporting "adverb". But it can also be parsed as *"is"*, which **can't** normally stand alone like that. I see nothing to be gained by attempting to apply characterisations which are at best capable of making broad distinctions for clear-cut contexts, which this one isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. A sentence like this shows how imperfect the distinction between a regular verb and a linking verb (copula) is: there are arguments for calling it either in your example.

On the one hand, you could say that "xenophobia remains here" is much like "xenophobia is bad", which is clearly a copula plus subject complement: the last word is a property that is assigned to the subject.

However, the somewhat artificial convention defining copulae says that an adverbial phrase is normally not considered a subject complement: only nominal phrases (basically adjectives, pronouns, and nouns) can be subject complements. For that reason, one would normally say *remains* is not a copula in your example, but an **ordinary intransitive verb**.

Comment: Does this remain true even with an adjective predicate like _true_?

Comment: @JohnLawler: Heh, does what remain true exactly? In your example, I'd call it a copula + subject complement, and I believe that is the conventional label. But I would personally have no problem with calling it a regular verb with a predicative adjective, like "he came in first".

Comment: I don't think there's any real copula in English, beyond perhaps _be,_ which is, gods know, unusual enough in every way to deserve its own category label. There are [several hundred verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/there-levin.pdf), for instance, that govern _There_-Insertion, which is supposed to require a "copula". That seems like too much copulation to me.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Haha, isn't that last bit a contradiction in terms? In any case, when you say "there is no such thing as x", I get a bit rebellious. What you are really doing is using certain criteria to test it against. But don't you think it would be better if we first established which criteria are essential? For we can only argue for or against the usefulness of a label if we agree on the criteria. (I'm assuming that by "x doesn't exist" you mean "x is not a practical and unambiguous term"; I know you don't believe that "copula" should exist the way a chair exists.)

Comment: The criteria that are essentially would presumably be those that are most reliable in distinguishing verbs/categories exhibiting different behaviours, whilst at the same time being as simple/succinct an inventory of criteria as possible. (Or put another way, "doing good science".)

Comment: There-insertion is one criterion proposed for helping to distinguish "unaccusative" vs "unergative" verbs. It's certainly more reliable than the original poster's criterion, but it may run into problems in that the grammaticality of 'there' insertion may not depend solely on the identity of the verb (e.g. "*There worked three children" seems overtly odd, but "?There now worked thousands of women and children at the factory" seems a bit more acceptable).

Comment: @NeilCofey: Okay, so are you saying that no reasonably reliable criteria can be found to define copulae and subject complements? I remember as a child I resisted at first when my teacher in elementary school told me that "is" does not have an object, but a subject complement. "He is a man" and "he hits a man" seemed very similar constructions. But that was when I only knew Germanic languages: later, when I learned Romance languages and Greek, "copula + subject complement" seemed a very useful grand pattern that provides insight in the way all IE languages evolved and work now.

Comment: Oh, here we go again. I use the term "subject complement" to mean a complement clause that is a subject, like the first 3 words in _Bill's kicking Harry was unnecessary._ I don't use it for predicate adjectives or predicate nouns. I realize that CGEL, for instance, has its own uses for the phrase, and so do others; but that's why linguists always give examples. Oh, and I should add that I don't use the terms "unaccusative" or "unergative" at all, ever -- they strike me as extremely poor terminological engineering.

Comment: @JohnLawler: That is actually quite funny: I now realize how "subject complement" is an extremely ambiguous term, mainly because "complement" is ambiguous (but also because noun adjectives are intrinsically ambiguous: the relation between the two nouns in a noun adjective is inherently unclear). Do you know of any alternative to the word "complement" in a predicate frame? It's not a bad word, and of course I use it too, but it could perhaps be a bit more specific, like "complement to a verb"; but that is rather long. I have wrestled with this before.

Comment: I don't really know which constructions you use it to represent; predicate adjectives and predicate nouns are just predicates that don't happen to be verbs, and mostly I just call them predicates because that's what I'm interested in.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I have always called both together [subject complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement).

Comment: I don't see any particular need for a special term for them both; if "predicate" by itself doesn't do it, you could say "nonverbal predicates". Those are the ones that need auxiliary _be._ See my [Logic Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler: Alas, I don't have a PDF reader installed at the moment. Yes, you could use that; but then how do you distinguish between "I am that man" and "you made me that man"? The latter is conventionally called an object complement.

Comment: The latter actually **is** an object complement, or at least part of one. I.e, it's the remains of an infinitive clause where the predicate is _be that man_, and the subject is 1sg. The subject has been deleted by Equi with _me_, and auxiliary infinitive _to be_ has been deleted (governed by _make_), leaving behind only that NP. Mostly these things are the remains of deceased clauses, as McCawley called them.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be agonising over a categorisation that may be a bit pointless in the first place.

In your dichotomy between "intransitive" vs "linking" verbs: (a) what grammatical phenomena are inherent to each of these categories? (b) what grammatical tests are there to decide on the categorisation in a given instance? If your categorisation is too woolly to have answers to (a) and (b), I wonder how useful it is...?

The categorisation of verbs according to "transitivity" is quite a complex issue. As an example of the kind of complexity at stake, I'd recommend e.g. Legendre & Sorace, "Auxiliaries and Intransitivity in French and in Romance" in Godard (ed), "Fundamental Issues in the Romance Languages". They're obviously concerned mainly with Romance languages rather than English, but the underlying issues potentially apply beyond the Romance languages.

Comment: I believe the hard-though-perhaps-arbitrary criterion is that a subject complement should be nominal, not adverbial like here.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, a linking verb connects the subject to a noun that redefines it OR to an adjective that describes it. In this case, "in our society" does not "rename" xenophobia,  but it does describe it.

For example, "Bob is the chairman." "Bob" and "the chairman" are two ways of identifying the same person, so "is" is a linking verb here.

"Bob is hungry." "Hungry" is not another name for "Bob", but it is an adjective that describes Bob. "is" serves as a linking verb.

An interesting rule of thumb I just stumbled across is, Try replacing the verb that you think may be a linking verb with "is". Does the sentence still make sense and convey a similar idea? If so, it probably is a linking verb.

"Bob feels hungry." Replace "feels" with "is": "Bob is hungry." Yes, it's still basically the same idea. "Feels" is working as a linking verb.

"Bob feels a pain in his foot." Replace "feels" with "is": "Bob is a pain in his foot." No, that doesn't make sense, definately not the same idea. "Feels" is not working as a linking verb.

In this case, "Xenophobia IS in our society." Yes, that makes perfect sense and is a similar idea. "Remains" is working as a linking verb.

Comment: *People **walk** in the park. People **are** in the park.* (I.e. I don't think this test works: noöne would call "walk" a copula; you're rather testing against transitive verbs.)

Comment: @cerberus: That's why it's a "rule of thumb" and not an absolute rule! You could argue it works because the meaning is not "similar", you've lost the idea of perambulating here, in a way that you don't lose meaning when going from "feels" or "becomes" to "is". But sure, "similar" is a vague test.

Comment: Right, OK, "without much loss of meaning" makes sense. But "she became a teacher" and "she was a teacher"? Oh, well, we are essentially agreed.